# Which types correspond to discrete and continuous distributions?

Tags: r

I am a new beginner in R and programming in general, and I'm confused about categorical, continuous, and discrete variables.

I believe for variables with the type `<chr>`, they are categorical variables. But do they also count as discrete variables?
Also, with type `<int>`, are they continuous or discrete? Tried to find it online but found mixed answers and got confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out: https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/edu/power-pouvoir/ch8/5214817-eng.htm

Comment: This give the definition for the tibble types you are referring to https://tibble.tidyverse.org/articles/types.html

Comment: “categorical” and “discrete” are two words that mean the same thing in this context, and they are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a question about statistics not about R.

In statistics, categorical and discrete variables are the same thing. They all represent a variable where you can't or don't want to represent values in the middle. So "species" is categorical because there is "Home sapiens" and "Homo erectus" but there is no 0.5 "Homo sapiens"/0.5 "Homo erectus".

Note that, some variables can be continuous and but you choose to represent it as categorical for simplicity. For example, color of human skin is often portraited as "black" or "white" but there is near infinite diversity of tones, which are better represented by the continuous variable "concentration of melanin on skin". A continuous variable is one that is not discrete.

Now that is statistics. R can store data on different formats, some directly related to these statistics, some not. R stores numbers in three different (and confusing) formats. int for integer, double for numbers with digits and numeric also for numbers with digits. This is due to programming reasons, and are irrelevant for modeling. Placing any of those in a model will lead R treating it as continuous variables.

Some forms of storing data are not related to statistics at all. Character stores text. Just text, no connection with statistics. Logical is for true and false values. Again no immediate connection with stats.

There is only one special format for storing categorical variables: factor. It just so happens that R convert text to factor automatically when using it models.

Hope that helps